# Busca avançada Laravel

Tags: laravel

**Montar tabela de acordo a busca**

Boa tarde, pessoal, é possível criar uma busca e montar um tabela de acordo com o resultado

**EXEMPLO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function envia(Request $request){
  $bcentrocusto = $request->get('c');
  $bunidade = $request->get('u');
  $bproduto = $request->get('p');

  if(isset($bcentrocusto, $bunidade, $bproduto)){
    echo 'v1';
    return Redirect::to(route('requisicao.index'));

  }elseif(isset($bunidade, $bproduto)){
    echo 'v2';
    return Redirect::to(route('solicitacao.index'));

  }elseif(isset($bunidade, $bproduto)){
    echo 'v3';
    return Redirect::to(route('compra.index'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Olá Frodrigues. Você poderia ser mais especifico na sua duvida? Da forma que você elaborou sua pergunta fica difícil te ajudar, é importante que você mostre para nós o que já fez e onde esta a sua dificuldade. [Veja como fazer uma pergunta a partir de um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Guilherme, postei um modelo que fiz. A ideia é a seguinte: De acordo os request que receber eu monto a tela com os filtros. EX: se o user quiser filtrar pelos tres, dai monto um relario, se ele quiser apenas com dois, monto e assim por diante...

Comment: Se esse redirect dentro do if tivesse funcionado tinha resolvido, mas nao esta funcionando. Pensei em redirecionar a view de acordo com o if. Mas não sei se isso é possovel